# Deploying multiple version of a single application with Helm in the same namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a situation where i have an application for which i would like to run several set of instances configured differently. I guess from readying online, people would usually having several version of the same application in your clusters.

But let me somewhat describe the use case at the high level. The application is a component that takes as configuration a a dataset and a set of instructions stating how to process the dataset. The dataset is actually a datasource.

So in the same namespace, we would like for instance process 2 dataset.

So it is like having two deployments for the same application. Each dataset has different requirements, hence we should be able to have deployment1 scale to 10 instance and deployement 2 scale to 5 instance.

The thing is it is the same application and so far it is the same helm chart, and deployment definition.

The question is what are the different options that exist to handle that at this time.

examples, pointers, article are welcome.

So far i found the following article as the most promising:

https://itnext.io/support-multiple-versions-of-a-service-in-kubernetes-using-helm-ce26adcb516d

Another thing i though about is duplicating the deployment chart into 2 sub-charts of which the folder name differ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Helm supports this pretty straightforwardly.

In Helm terminology, you would write a *chart* that describes how to install one copy of your application.  This creates Kubernetes Deployments and other manifests; but it has templating that allows parts of the application to be filled in at deploy time.  One copy of the installation is a *release*, but you can have multiple releases, in the same or different Kubernetes namespaces.

For example, say you have a YAML template for a Kubernetes deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-processor
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: DATASET_NAME
              value: {{ .Values.dataset }}
          # and the other things that usually go into a container spec
```

When you go to deploy this, you can create a *values file*:

```yaml
# a.yaml
replicas: 10
dataset: dataset-1
```

And you can deploy it:

```sh
helm install \
  one        \ # release name
  .          \ # chart location
  -f a.yaml    # additional values to use
```

If you use `kubectl get deployment`, you will see `one-processor`, and if you look at it in detail, you will see it has 10 replicas and its environment variable is set to `dataset-1`.

You can create a second deployment with different settings in the same namespace:

```yaml
# b.yaml
replicas: 5
dataset: dataset-2
```

```sh
helm install two . -f b.yaml
```

Or in a different namespace:

```sh
helm install three . -n other-namespace -f c.yaml
```

It's theoretically possible to have a chart that only installs other subcharts (an *umbrella chart*), but there are some practical issues with it, most notably that Helm will want to install only one copy of a given chart no matter where it appears in the chart hierarchy.  There are other higher-level tools like [Helmsman](https://github.com/Praqma/helmsman) and [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) that would allow you to basically describe these multiple `helm install` commands in a single file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Meanwhile few questions. (1) It seems in your example only the release name is changed at deploy time, the dataset of each release is the same however. How would you also ensure that the dataset variable takes different value for different release ?

Comment: (2) So i guess it is all about the templating, as your example goes actually in the same direction of the article here: https://itnext.io/support-multiple-versions-of-a-service-in-kubernetes-using-helm-ce26adcb516d . However in that example i am not sure how the author ensure that the release have different name, could you have a quick look and say, how what does compare to you

Comment: You can deploy with different values files, which change what's visible in `.Values` in the templating; I've tried to clarify this a little with an example for the `b.yaml` file with different replica count and dataset.  Helm doesn't allow multiple releases in the same namespace with the same name, so you're guaranteed the `{{ .Release.Name }}-processor` name will be unique.

Comment: The big example in that article creates several Deployments based on the configured values.  That's a somewhat more complex setup than you probably need here; most charts I've seen write out the YAML for each Deployment they need to create, even though they all look pretty similar.  I would write multiple `templates/*-deployment.yaml` files rather than try to provide every Deployment setting through configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I get your example and explanation cristal clear. However just for completeness and comparison, while I see the unique release names in your example, I can’t see it in his example. I don’t see how this will result at deployment time in multiple release henceforth avoiding the clash of release name.

Comment: oh my bad i think i get what you said about his approach, he is not having different instance based on the release here. He is doing different deployment indicated by `svc-{{ .name }}`

Comment: So to sum up, if i followed u well, here we are describing two approaches, either you create multiple deployment, or create multiple release name associated/using different values.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can "cascade" the values YAML files to achieve what you want. For example, you could define `common.yaml` to be all the common settings for your application. Then, each separate instance would be a second YAML file.

Here is an example. Let's say that the file `common.yaml` looks like this:

```
namespace: myapp-dev
pod-count: 1
use_ssl: true
image-name: debian:buster-slim
... more ...
```

Let's say you want two Deployments, own that scales to 5 replicas and one that scales to 10. You would create two more files:

```yaml
# local5.yaml
pod-count: 5
```

and

```yaml
# local10.yaml
pod-count: 10
```

Note that you do *not* have to repeat the settings in `common.yaml`. To deploy the five-replica version you do something like this:

```sh
$ helm install -f common.yaml -f local5.yaml five .
```

To deploy the 10-replica version:

```sh
$ helm install -f common.yaml -f local10.yaml ten .
```

The YAML files cascade with the later file overriding the earlier.